# grails: dynamically adding associations

Tags: plugins, grails, groovy, metaprogramming

Mormally setting up one-to-many associations is easy. Take for example:

```
class Author {         
  String firstName 
  String lastName 

  static hasMany = [books: Book]        

  static constraints = { 
      books(nullable: true) 
  } 
} 

class Book {         
  String title 
  Author author 
  Publisher publisher 

  static constraints = { 
    author(nullable: true) 
    publisher(nullable: true) 
  } 
}
```

However, if I've already setup the Author domain without knowing Book at all, there is no `static hasMany = [books: Book]` specified initially. Later, I want to add a Book domain and want to add `static hasMany = [books: Book]` to Author. Could I do this with a plugin? If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: What's preventing you from just updating your Author class and adding in the hasMany books?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to update the Author class, you could create your own association class.

```
class AuthorsToBooks {
    Author author
    static belongsTo = [Book: book]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the good one!  still, what I need to do just to add "static hasMany = [books: Book] " dynamically to Author class, without creating this new association class?

Comment: I guess you could add a list of books to you domain class directly and add it to the transients so it doesn't persist.